# How can I run validations on derived values for new objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model that has several attributes that are provided at creation. The model also has some additional attributes that are derived from the provided attributes, which I also want to calculate at creation. More problematically, I want to be able to run validations on these derived values (since there are inputs that are valid on their own that lead to invalid derived values).

The problem is that when I do this:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :given1, :given2, :derived

  before_validation :derivation
  validates_uniqueness_of :derived

  def derivation
    self.derived = self.given1 + self.given2
  end
end

MyClass.new(:given1 => aNumber, :given2 => otherNumber)
```

I always get errors saying I can't add `nil` to `nil`. Apparently `self.attribute` is nil until farther into the validation & creation process.

Obviously I could set my derived values in a later stage, and add a custom validation that works on the given attributes, but that would entail doing the derivation twice, which wouldn't be very DRY.

Is there some other way to get at assigned but not yet validated attributes in the `before_validates` stage?

Edit: To clarify, I want to call `MyClass.new(:given1 => aNumber, :given2 => otherNumber)` and have the derived value calculated *before* the validations check, so that the validations check as if I had called `MyClass.new(:given1 => aNumber, :given2 => otherNumber, :derived => aNumber + otherNumber)`. The problem is that I can't seem to access the passed-in values for `:given1` and `:given2` in a `before_validations` method.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations)

Comment: My bad.  I was confusing attr_accessible with attr_accessor.  The documentation of attr_accessible is new with Rails 3.2, and I am unfamiliar with it.  I will delete my bad comments.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking to be honest. What exactly are you running to set the values of given1 and given2. I will write a little explanation as to what attr_accessible does and if you need more help then just comment and I'll edit as needed

Comment: @LeoCorrea: I'm running `MyClass.new(:given1 => aNumber, :given2 => otherNumber)`, and I want the validations to run on `:given1 => aNumber, :given2 => otherNumber, :derived => aNumber + otherNumber`. Except, of course, my derivation is more complex than just adding the 2 numbers together. The whole attr_accessible deal is a side issue that arose from Marlin being unfamiliar with 3.2; it has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: I wrote my own little snippet of code that pretty much does the same thing you are doing but with a user and it works just fine. What exactly is the error that you are getting? Are you assigning `aNumber` and `otherNumber`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my own snippet of code that looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name

  validates :email, uniqueness: true

  before_validation :derivation

  def derivation
    self.email = self.first_name + self.last_name
  end
end
```

Running the following yielded no errors:

```
»  u = User.new first_name: "leo", last_name: "correa"
=> #<User:0x007ff62dd8ace0> {
                      :id => nil,
              :first_name => "leo",
               :last_name => "correa",
                   :email => nil,
              :created_at => nil,
              :updated_at => nil,
}
»  u.valid?
  User Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'leocorrea' LIMIT 1
=> true
```

Running `u.save` saved the record successfully and upon repeating the `User.new` and saving that new record it returned with `ROLLBACK` because email was already used.

In any case, make sure you are assigning whatever variables you are using to the given1, given2 and whatever the result is make sure is not giving you false either because it will cancel the before_validate callback and the record won't save.

Comment: Leo, note in your example that e-mail is nil; when derivation is called, it sees self.first_name & self.last_name as nil, rather than the values you passed to it. That's my problem.

Comment: What are you talking about? I see email is nil when I first call `new` but first_name and last_name are set with the values passed in. Once I call `valid?` it triggers the before_validation and assigns email.

Comment: Otherwise, if `first_name` and `last_name` were nil I would've gotten an error instead of `true`

Comment: Hmmmm, I see. I'm calling some methods on my given values (value.floor, etc) and I keep getting an error that I can't call that method on nil.

Comment: Can you post the exact command you are running with hard coded values? Are you sure the values you are passing in are being set?

Comment: Never mind, I'm an idiot. It was failing on a couple tests where I deliberately didn't pass in 1 or more of the given values.